# SpannableString not works android

Tags: android

I have a layout `contact_info.xml` , that contains some info about the event of contacts, I want to get the text of `textview` in the layout and add extra text to it. The added extra texts font must be different from the `textview` font

I tried , but didn't succeeded

ContactInfoActivity.java

```
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "CrochetPattern.ttf");

        String evenType=SearchListActivity.eventType;
        Spannable sb = new SpannableString( evenType );
        sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(font.BOLD), 0, evenType.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
txtvwEventType.setText(txtvwEventType.getText()+"  "+sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `evenType.length()` to `evenType.length() - 1`

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by this line:

> txtvwEventType.setText(txtvwEventType.getText()+"  "+sb);

append txtvwEventType.getText() to sb, do not use + to concate them

Comment: I am unable to use append on xtvwEventType.setText or sb

Comment: Use SpannableStringBuilder instead of Spannable

Comment: sb.append(txtvwEventType.getText());
txtvwEventType.setText(sb);........ not works

Comment: ```Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "CrochetPattern.ttf");
  SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
  sb.append(txtvwEventType.getText());
  int start = sb.length();
  sb.append(SearchListActivity.eventType);
  sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(font.BOLD), start, sb.length(),     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
txtvwEventType.setText(sb);```